# Automatically calling class function after init

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-class

I want to automate a class method which would be called right after `__init__` has completed.

e.g,

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        initialization statement
    def post_init(self):
        #this should be automatically called after completion of __init__ function.
        some statement
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: call `self.post_init()` inside `__init__`, but if you are not passing any extra args to `.post_init`, why can't use all statements inside `__init__`?

Comment: ```post_init()``` is a time consuming function and takes a while to complete.and the class is to be instantiated inside another class as a property. So if  i use it inside init() then I am unable to instantiate the class untill both methods have completed execution.

Comment: what i want is instantiate the class with ```init()``` and then call the second function.

Comment: Do you want to call the second function in background and call the dependent functions after the background task completes?

Comment: Do it matter? If you instantiate and you cannot wait the finish of post_init, I assume you are doing multithread, but so you have a incomplete class, so you can have bugs. Often you just have a status `__is_fully_initialized`, and you check at every function call. In case of need you do post_init(). (this trick is used on such slow case: doing work only when needed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run `post_init` automatically after `__init__` for this class and all inheriting classes you need to mess with how objects are instantiated using metaclasses. By default when you `__call__` a class using `A()` it invokes a `__new__` to create a new object and then an `__init__` method of that object. You want to add the `post_init` to that sequence

```py
class MyMetaclass(type):
  def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    new_obj = type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    new_obj.post_init()
    return new_obj

class A(metaclass=MyMetaclass):
  def __init__(self):
    print('init called')

  def post_init(self):
    print('post init called')
```

You can verify that

```
>>> A()
init called
post init called
<__main__A at 0x7f3988e2c6a0>
```